# highcharts map Zoom by a single click

Tags: highcharts, click, zooming

i found this example that allows to set double click zoom to true. I need to  be able to zoom in a single click how can I do that in high charts.

DoubleClick zoom example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/doubleclickzoomto/

```
 mapNavigation: {
   enabled: true,
   enableDoubleClickZoomTo: true
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`mapZoom`](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps#Chart.mapZoom) after [`click`](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps#chart.events.click) event. In click `event` you have access to values of clicked place on a map.

Note: You may need to create some if-else statement, to prevent clicks on legend, +/- buttons etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use zoomTo() , it'll zoom to a particular point wherever you have clicked 
here is a fiddle
```

[oneclickzoomTo()](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/members/point-zoomto/)